# Use azure data factory Updating Azure Machine Learning models

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

When I use data factory to update Azure ML models like the document said (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-azure-ml-update-resource-activity),

I faced one problem:

```
The blob reference: test/model.ilearner has an invalid or missing file extension. Supported file extensions for this output type are: ".csv, .tsv, .arff".'.
```

I have searched the problem and found this solution:

> https://disqus.com/home/discussion/thewindowsazureproductsite/data_factory_create_predictive_pipelines_using_data_factory_and_machine_learning_microsoft_azure/ .

But my linked service for the outputs of training service pipeline and update service pipeline are already different.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you identified a solution, @chenxu? I'm experiencing the same problem when trying to consume the experiment through it's webservice using C#...

Comment: Sorry I'm not very sure about the solution as this problem happened long time ago. I guess my problem was caused by the model name was mistake. There was one more space in the model name in ML studio, but when I set it in ADF, I missed the space. I'm not very sure, but you can have a check about that, as the space missing is difficult to detect...

Comment: No worries, thank you for the reply! I ended up determining the cause of my problem, and it was the same sort of thing--the experiment was expecting a specific parameter, and what I was slightly different.