# Azure ML Experiment Batch Webservice Call Fails with Invalid Output Extension

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have an Azure webjob that is calling a ML training experiment via HttpRequests, leveraging the code generated in the ML webportal:

```
var request = new BatchExecutionRequest()
            {
                Inputs = new Dictionary<string, AzureBlobDataReference>() {
                    {
                        "input1",
                        new AzureBlobDataReference()
                        {
                            ConnectionString = _connectionString,
                            RelativeLocation = $"{_containerName}/{experimentId}/{tenantId}/{trainingDataFileName}"
                        }
                    },
                },

                Outputs = new Dictionary<string, AzureBlobDataReference>() {
                    {
                        "output1",
                        new AzureBlobDataReference()
                        {
                            ConnectionString = "azureStorageConnectionString",
                            RelativeLocation = $"{_containerName}/{experimentId}/{tenantId}/Model_2018421.ilearner"
                        }
                    },
                },

                GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                }
            };
```

However, the request fails with the following message:

> The blob reference:
>   experiments/experimentId/TenantId/Model_2018421.ilearner
>   has an invalid or missing file extension. Supported file extensions
>   for this output type are: \\".csv, .tsv, .arff\\"

I'm pretty confused about this, since it's written right the documentation all over the place that if I'm expecting a trained model to use ".ilearner" as the file extension for the model.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920098/use-azure-data-factory-updating-azure-machine-learning-models) asking about the same error leveraging the DataFactory, and also [this question on datascience.stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27397/azure-machine-learning-model-retraining-problem). Neither one had any clues, answers, or other follow up.

Any insight on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for your "Don't Overthink It" moment of the day:

I needed to provide TWO output blob file references:

```
var request = new BatchExecutionRequest()
            {
                Inputs = new Dictionary<string, AzureBlobDataReference>() {
                    {
                        "input1",
                        new AzureBlobDataReference()
                        {
                            ConnectionString = _connectionString,
                            RelativeLocation = $"{_containerName}/{experimentId}/{tenantId}/{trainingDataFileName}.csv"
                        }
                    },
                },

                Outputs = new Dictionary<string, AzureBlobDataReference>() {
                    {
                        "output1",
                        new AzureBlobDataReference()
                        {
                            ConnectionString = _connectionString,
                            RelativeLocation = $"{_containerName}/{experimentId}/{tenantId}/{outputFileNameCsv}.csv"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "output2",
                        new AzureBlobDataReference()
                        {
                            ConnectionString = _connectionString,
                            RelativeLocation = $"{_containerName}/{experimentId}/{tenantId}/{outputFileNameIlearner}.ilearner"
                        }
                    },
                },

                GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                }
            };
```

There's an old saying in American English about not making assumptions, and I assumed the second output was an optional parameter used in batch operations. Since I'm not actually looking for more than one result from each call, I thought I was safe to remove the second output parameter.

TL/DR: Keep all the parameters the webservice portal's "Consume" tab generates, and make sure the first one is a .csv file reference.